# Как отображать различные данные в ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

У меня есть ListView, который берет данные из List`a. В листе есть bool переменная StartPrice. Мне нужно чтобы в ListView отображался текст в зависимости от значения данной переменной. Не подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

```
namespace graduate_work
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PageServiceByName : ContentPage
    {
        public PageServiceByName(List<Service> services)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ListView listService = new ListView()
            {
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                ItemsSource = services.Select(s => new {s.NameService.nameService, s.Price, s.StartPrice, s.Specialist.Name, s.Specialist.Address }),
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label labelNameService = new Label { FontSize = 16, FontFamily = "Roboto", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5147AC") };
                    labelNameService.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "nameService");

                    Label labelPrice = new Label { FontSize = 16, FontFamily = "Roboto", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5147AC") };
                    labelPrice.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Price");

                    Label labelNameSpecialist = new Label { FontSize = 16, FontFamily = "Roboto", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5147AC") };
                    labelNameSpecialist.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

                    Label labelAddress = new Label { FontSize = 16, FontFamily = "Roboto", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5147AC") };
                    labelAddress.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Address");

                    Label labelStartPrice = new Label { FontSize = 16, FontFamily = "Roboto", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5147AC") };
                    labelStartPrice.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "StartPrice");

                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Padding = new Thickness(10, 10),
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                            Children = { labelNameService, labelStartPrice, labelPrice, labelNameSpecialist, labelAddress }
                        }
                    };
                })
            };
            this.Content = new StackLayout { Children = { listService } };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Converters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters ?

Comment: Почему все в C#...? У вас ведь есть отличный инструмент по типу XAML, весь приведенный код из вопроса должен быть там, и никак иначе. Что касается самого вопроса, то у вас должен быть класс, который описывает один конкретный объект, в этом классе должны быть публичные свойства. Имея это, вы в `set` свойстве `bool` задаете значение другому свойству на то, которое надо. Ваша сейчас проблема в структуре, которую вы не делаете. И да `bool переменная StartPrice` - странно видеть "стартовую цену" в виде "bool"...

Comment: Это случаем не ChatGPT вам такой код написал? А то при условии, что вы так профессионально накидали биндингов в C#, учитывая что никто в интернете так не делает, то вопрос связанный с отсутствием знаний про стили `Style` и триггеры `Style.Triggers` выглядит странновато. У меня диссонанс. Используйте `DataTrigger` в стилях для изменения поведения леяута на основе значений свойств.